# Hosting Laravel 5.8 on Azure Web-App + MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, azure

I am trying to host a completed Laravel 5.8 application on Azure Web Apps with MySQL. I can successfully deploy from GitHub, install Composer, update dependencies, cleared the cache, browse to the landing page, and view all static pages. But when I try to migrate or do anything with the DB, I get

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access Denied

I have changed the port, username, and password in .env to those in `MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb.ini.` I have tried leaving it blank and have been attempting to update the same in `cofig\database.php,` but no progress.

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:***
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://*****.azurewebsites.net/

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=***
DB_DATABASE=localdb
DB_USERNAME=***
DB_PASSWORD=***
```

Using the code from https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/MySQL-in-app

```php
// Parsing connnection string
foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'MYSQLCONNSTR_') !== 0) {
        continue;
    }

    $servername = preg_replace('/^.*Data Source=(.+?);.*$/', "\\1", $value);
    $dbname = preg_replace('/^.*Database=(.+?);.*$/', "\\1", $value);
    $username = preg_replace('/^.*User Id=(.+?);.*$/', "\\1", $value);
    $password = preg_replace('/^.*Password=(.+?)$/', "\\1", $value);
}

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: '.$conn->connect_error);
}

echo 'connection successful<br/>';
$conn->close();
```

The app displays: connection successful,

But I don't know where to put what in the Laraval App files.
Please help.

Comment: Try asking the technical support of the server, they may help you with this.

Comment: DB_HOST, looks not right check [Connect applications to Azure Database for MySQL | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-connection-string#targetText=Get%20the%20connection%20string%20details,and%20other%20database%20connection%20parameters.)

Comment: Mohamed, I've seen this article: I can't find the connection string in Azure. The article is dated. I am about to give-up and just publish to a VM.